# Multires baking requires a multires object

Tags: uv, modifiers, normals, baking

I have an object with mirror and multires unapplied, and I want to bake it with higher details while maintaining optimization, but I get the message noted in the title of this post.

Here are my configurations:

[image]
[image]

Comment: You probably selected another object besides one with multires. You should select only adjacent object; probably [this thread with similar question](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?237598-Normal-Baking-from-Multires-Modifier) may help you. Also it seems you shouldn't have Mirror modifier further in the stack; it can provide you with such error

Comment: Then just apply the mirror?

Comment: I wouldn't say; you'll lose all the details from Multiresolution modifier in this case (as you can't move Mirror upper in the stack than Multiresolution).

Answer (score 8):

To resolve this error message you need to leave **only** `Multires` modifier and apply the others.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. For me, the "apply base" button in the multires modifier fixed this.